# in Oracle ADF, I want to make an af:query component submit search on each keystroke

Tags: oracle-adf

I have an af:query component that is correctly querying a table when I enter values, and hit the search button.

I would like to automatically search when a key is pressed whenever the cursor is in one of the query fields. eg behaving like autocomplete in List of Values.

Any suggestions on how to do this?

I was experimenting with a af:clientlistener, but this does not have visibility of key presses within the af:query component.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that this will result in decent performance - and might actually be annoying to the end user to get a query in the form populated on each keystroke.
In any case, I don't think you can do this with the query component - maybe you should be building your own search screen for this. 
If you are interested in having LOV for query fields this might help:
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/dependent_lovs_in_an_afquery_c
https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/adf_query_with_parameters_and_1